# Add object to an KnockoutJS after input validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to validate the user input before adding the object to an observable. For example if I have two fields, say Quantity and Price, before adding the object to the observable I want to validate the user input.
How can I achieve this behavioral?

The code that I have so far:

```
self.productPriceAdd = function () {
    var newPrice = {
        Quantity: self.newProductPriceEntry.Quantity(),
        Price: self.newProductPriceEntry.Price(),
        ProductBarcode: self.productPrices().Barcode
    }
    self.productPrices().ProductSalePrices().push(newPrice);
    self.productPrices().ProductSalePrices(self.productPrices().ProductSalePrices());
    self.newProductPriceEntry.Quantity(null);
    self.newProductPriceEntry.Price(null);
}
```

The user interface looks somethig like this:

[image]

So after the user clicks the Add button, two error messages should be displayed, one for each empty field.

My HTML code:

```
<!-- ko if: productPrices() -->
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title"><b data-bind="text: productPrices().Name"></b></h2>
    </div>
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Quantity")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Price")
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        <tbody data-bind="foreach: productPrices().ProductSalePrices()">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b data-bind="text: Quantity"></b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b data-bind="text: Price"></b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.productPriceRemove" class="btn btn-defaul">Remove</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

        <tbody data-bind="with: newProductPriceEntry">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Quantity " placeholder="Quantity">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" data-bind="value: Price " placeholder="Price">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.productPriceAdd" class="btn btn-defaul">Add</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</div>
<a href="#" data-bind="click: productPriceSave" class="btn btn-defaul">Save</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Knockout-Validation. It is a Knockout plugin that simplifies the validation process.

https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation

Comment: I've used Knockout-Validation and it's displaying the appropriate error message, but I still can to add invalid objects to the observable variable, for example, empty fields. Is there any way to check if there are validation errors and to prevent adding the invalid object to the observable?

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution I found is to check for false values for **Quantity** and **Price** field. Are evaluated to false the following types: false, "", undefined and null.
So, the full working code:

```
self.productPrices = ko.observable();
self.newProductPriceEntry = {
    Quantity: ko.observable("").extend({ required: true }),
    Price: ko.observable("").extend({ required: true })
}

self.productPriceAdd = function () {
    var newPrice = {
        Quantity: self.newProductPriceEntry.Quantity(),
        Price: self.newProductPriceEntry.Price(),
        ProductBarcode: self.productPrices().Barcode
    }

    if (newPrice.Price && newPrice.Quantity) {
        self.productPrices().ProductSalePrices().push(newPrice);
        self.productPrices().ProductSalePrices(self.productPrices().ProductSalePrices());
    }
    self.newProductPriceEntry.Quantity(null);
    self.newProductPriceEntry.Price(null);
}
```

So what I am doing is to push the object into the observable only if the condition is true. Then set the observables to null to clear the fields.

For the number part validation I used the **number** HTML5 attribute.